# Yii 2 is adding a hyphen to the start of the sort name when using createUrl()

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using `Yii 2` and I have created a [Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) and [Sort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html) system and have the following code:

Here is the generalized code:

```
$sql = $this->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table WHERE some_id=:some_id");
$sql->bindValue(':some_id', $this->some_id);
$count = $sql->queryScalar();

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_id=:some_id',
    'params' => [':some_id' => $this->some_id],
    'totalCount' => $count,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'sort_way_1' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_2' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_2' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 1',
            ],
            'sort_way_2' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_4' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_4' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 2',
            ],
            'sort_way_3' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_5' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_5' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 3',
            ],
            'sort_way_4' => [
                'asc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_6' => SORT_ASC, 'col_3' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['col_1' => SORT_DESC, 'col_6' => SORT_DESC, 'col_3' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Sort Way 4',
            ],
        ],
        'enableMultiSort' => false,
        'defaultOrder' => ['sort_way_1' => SORT_DESC],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'defaultPageSize' => $this->per_page,
        'pageSize' => $this->per_page,
        'pageSizeLimit' => [5,100],
        'pageSizeParam' => 'per_page',
        'totalCount' => $count,
    ],
]);
```

Now for my sorting links I attempted to create the URL's with the [createUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html#createUrl%28%29-detail) method and everything works fine, except for the fact it appends a `-` to the start of the sort attribute name in the URL (apart from the first sort method).

**Example:**

```
http://example.com/some_dir/?page=1&sort=sort_way_1 (good)
http://example.com/some_dir/?page=1&sort=-sort_way_2 (bad)
```

I then tried doing it with the [LinkSorter Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linksorter.html) but I got the same results.

I dug into the code a bit and found the below code inside the `sort.php` [createSortParam](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Sort.php#L335) method:

```
foreach ($directions as $attribute => $direction) {
    $sorts[] = $direction === SORT_DESC ? '-' . $attribute : $attribute;
}
```

This *appears* to be the culprit for the appended hyphen, but I'm not sure why it does it or why it doesn't add it to the first sorting attribute.

Does anyone have any more info on this or how to get around it? As with the appended hyphens the requested sorting method is coming back as invalid.

Comment: Do you want to sort both ways (ascending and descending) for sort_way_2?

Comment: @Marek Yes, that should be an option. But if they wanted to sort different to the default wouldn't it include `&direction=` in the URL?

Comment: No, it uses the hyphen to distinguish which direction to sort: `sort=-sort_way_2` is descending, `sort=sort_way_2` is accending. If you don't like that, you are on your own, you have to reimplement it. How difficult it is I don't know.

Comment: This is the default behavior. ASC - without hyphen, DESC - with hyphen. What's the exact problem? You want to replace it by something? By what in this case? Or the exception is thrown when you change order direction? But latter signals about error in your code.

Comment: @arogachev It's just a weird way of doing it is all. Can't say I have ever seen it done this way before, most sites/software does it by using asc/desc as a separate param. Not a huge deal, I can work around it if I have to. :)

Comment: @Marek Is there any way to only have ti show DESC sorting options as you were previously asking? I commented out the `asc` line in the `attributes` config for the sort instance but it didn't work.

Comment: @Brett I don't know, but you can try changing `'desc'` to `'asc'`, thus not having any `'desc'`.

Comment: @Marek Alright, no worries.